# Why does my token return NULL and how can I fix it?(c++)

Tags: c++, null, token, strtok

I've created a program to get a string input from a user and parse it into tokens and move a robot according to the input. The program is supposed to recognize these inputs(where x is an integer): "forward x" "back x" "turn left x" "turn right x" and "stop". The program does what it's supposed to for all commands except for "stop". When I type "stop" the program prints out "whats happening?" because I've written a line which states:

```
if(token == NULL)
{
    cout << "whats happening?" << endl;
}
```

**Why does token get NULL, and how can I fix this so it will read "stop" properly?**
here is the code:

```
bool stopper = 0;
void Navigator::manualDrive()
{
    VideoStream video(&myRobot, 0);//allows user to see what robot sees
    video.startStream();
    const int bufSize = 42;
    char uinput[bufSize];
    char delim[] = " ";
    char *token;

    while(stopper == 0)
    {
    cout << "Enter your directions below: " << endl;
    cin.getline(uinput,bufSize);
    Navigator::parseInstruction(uinput);
    }
}
/* parseInstruction(char *c) -- parses cstring instructions received
 * and moves robot accordingly
 */


void Navigator::parseInstruction(char * uinput)
{

    char delim[] = " ";
    char *token;


//  cout << "Enter your directions below: " << endl; 
//  cin.getline (uinput, bufSize);

    token=strtok(uinput, delim);
    if(token == NULL)
    {
        cout << "whats happening?" << endl;
    }
    if(strcmp("forward", token) == 0)
    {
        int inches;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        inches = atoi (token);
        double value = fabs(0.0735 * fabs(inches) - 0.0550);
        myRobot.forward(1, value);
    }
    else if(strcmp("back",token) == 0)
    {
        int inches;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        inches = atoi (token);
        double value = fabs(0.0735 * fabs(inches) - 0.0550);
        myRobot.backward(1/*speed*/, value/*time*/);
    }
    else if(strcmp("turn",token) == 0)
    {
        int degrees;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        if(strcmp("left",token) == 0)
        {
            token = strtok(uinput, delim);
            degrees = atoi (token);
            double value = fabs(0.00467 * degrees - 0.04);
            myRobot.turnLeft(1/*speed*/, value/*time*/);
        }


        else if(strcmp("right",token) == 0)
        {
            token = strtok(uinput, delim);
            degrees = atoi (token);
            double value = fabs(0.00467 * degrees - 0.04);
            myRobot.turnRight(1/*speed*/, value/*time*/);
        }
    }
    else if(strcmp("stop",token) == 0)
    {
        stopper = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Unknown command '" << token << "'\n";
    }
}
/* autoDrive() -- reads in file from ifstream, parses
 * and moves robot according to instructions in file
 */
void Navigator::autoDrive(string filename)
{
    const int bufSize = 42;
    char fLine[bufSize];
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("autodrive.txt", fstream::in);

    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        infile.getline(fLine, bufSize);
        Navigator::parseInstruction(fLine);
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

I need this to break out of the while loop and end manualDrive because in my driver program the next function called is autoDrive.
the autodrive.txt file looks like:

forward 2
turn right 30
back 3
turn left 50
stop

**Also I left out an important limitation on my program I'm not allowed to use string from the standard library**

Comment: post a sample of what's in autodrive.txt that's giving the bad behavior

Comment: I presume the program segfaults immediately after printing "whats happening?" because it passes NULL to strcmp?  If not, look for some line elsewhere in the program somewhere that also prints "what's happening?".  Is it possible that it does go to "autodrive" mode and there's a blank line somewhere in the file?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. No it does not go to autoDrive. It prints "whats happening?
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)     ./driver"
I have run autoDrive separately and i get segmentation fault on the last line of text which reads "stop" I'm going to edit my post with an example of what the text file looks like.

Comment: I cant reproduce the error with the code you gave. My suggestion is to write a minimal program which exploit this error, so other people can check whats the really defect is (which means on compilation unit which passes the compiler, without any external dependency). Also sometimes on the way to create such a program the error itself pops out very clearly.

Comment: I don't think there's a much of a mystery about what's happening - the input to `strtok()` is an empty string or a string of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The line of code:

```
token=strtok(uinput, delim);
```

will set `token` to NULL if `uinput` is empty or consists only of characters in the `delim` string.

Changing the code around your `NULL` check a little might help you figure out what's going on:

```
std::string original_uinput( uinput);  // save input string for debugging

token=strtok(uinput, delim);
if(token == NULL)
{
    cout << "whats happening? uinput was: " << original_uinput << endl;
}
```

In any case, `NULL` is a normal return from `strtok()` and your code needs to be prepared to handle it.

Comment: Just as a comment to your edit about not being allowed to use `std::string`:  I wasn't suggesting using `std::string` as a fix, only as something you could put in the code to help see why you might be getting a `NULL` return from `strtok()`.  How you might want to handle an empty (or all space) line from `cin` or `autodrive.txt` is up to you - you might want to simply return so you'll get another line or you might want to act as though a `stop` command had been issued. That's beside the point, which is that a `NULL` return from `strtok()` needs to be handled appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try running under a debugger and seeing what the value of uinput is when you get the error.

Also check the stack traceback at that point: when you get the error, is the input coming from manualDrive or autoDrive?